# React Native iOS HealthKit take times to load monthly data

Tags: ios, react-native, healthkit

React Native iOS HealthKit take times to load monthly data with 1 min and 6 mins max data's, it's take 10 mins to load data of full monthly data

I have used following code for this.

[https://medium.com/equinox-media-tech/react-native-app-with-healthkit-swift-aa44cca12ad7](https://stackoverflow.com)

can you please help me for resolved this issue.